# Change User Passwords

Tags: php, mysql

I just ran into a problem while developing a login system. I build a class that handles login for multiple users. I also created an admin area for the admin user. He will be able to add new users, to change his password, delete users, etc.

For now I managed to make the add new user and change the password part. The problem I have now it's about the change password part.

I have a table with this structure :

```
TABLE user
id int(11) AUTO INCREMENT
admin int(11) DEFAULT 0
username varchar(256)
password varchar(256)
```

The admin from the table defines the type of user, 0 is for normal user and 1 for admin user who can do what I described in above.

I have the following function to change the userpassword :

```
public function changeUserPassword($cusrn,$oldPass,$newPass,$newPassConfirm) {
    if(strlen($newPass) < 4) {
        $error = true;
        $message['error'] = true;
        $message['message'] = "The Password is to short";
        return json_encode($message);
    }
        elseif($newPass != $newPassConfirm) {
            $error = true;
            $message['error'] = true;
            $message['message'] = "Confirmed Password doesn't match";
            return json_encode($message);
        }
            elseif(!(ALLOW_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS == true) && preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $newPass)) {
                $error = true;
                $message['error'] = true;
                $message['message'] = "Special characters are not allowed";
                return json_encode($message);
            }
                elseif(!(ALLOW_NUMBERS == true) && preg_match('#\d#',$newPass)) {
                    $error = true;
                    $message['error'] = true;
                    $message['message'] = "Numbers are not allowed";
                    return json_encode($message);
                }
                    elseif(!isset($error)) {
                        $oldPass = hash_hmac('sha512',$oldPass,$this -> salt($cusrn,$oldPass));
                        $newPass = hash_hmac('sha512',$newPass,$this -> salt($cusrn,$newPass));
                        $sql = 'SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
                        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
                            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$cusrn,$newPass);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->bind_result($usrn,$passw);
                            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                                if( $cusrn == $usrn ) {
                                    if(!(strcmp($oldPass,$passw) == false)) {
                                        $error = true;
                                        $message['error'] = true;
                                        $message['message'] = "The current Password is incorrect";
                                        return json_encode($message);
                                    }
                                        elseif (!(strcmp($oldPass,$newPass) == false)) {
                                            $stmt->close();
                                            $sql = "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE username = '$usrn' LIMIT 1";
                                            if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
                                                $stmt->bind_param('s',$newPass);
                                                $stmt->execute();
                                                $stmt->close();
                                                $error = false;
                                                $message['error'] = false;
                                                $message['message'] = "Password successfuly changed";
                                                return json_encode($message);
                                            }
                                                else {
                                                    $error = true;
                                                    $message['error'] = true;
                                                    $message['message'] = "Cannot connect to database for updating";
                                                    return json_encode($message);
                                                }
                                        }
                                            else {
                                                $error = true;
                                                $message['error'] = true;
                                                $message['message'] = "New Password must not match the old one";
                                                return json_encode($message);
                                            }
                                }
                                    else {
                                        $error = true;
                                        $message['error'] = true;
                                        $message['message'] = "The current Username is incorrect";
                                        return json_encode($message);   
                                    }
                                }
                                    else {
                                        $error = true;
                                        $message['error'] = true;
                                        $message['message'] = "Cannot fetch data from the database";
                                        return json_encode($message);
                                    }
                            }
                                else {
                                    $error = true;
                                    $message['error'] = true;
                                    $message['message'] = "Cannot prepare database connection";
                                    return json_encode($message);   
                                }
                    }
                        else {
                            $error = true;
                            $message['error'] = true;
                            $message['message'] = "Check the PHP syntax | Something went wrong";
                            return json_encode($message);
                        }
}
```

The problem I have is that if I try to input a certain username it either throws me this :

```
 "Cannot fetch data from the database"
```

or it keeps telling me this :

```
 "The current Username is incorrect"
```

even if the username is correct. Though it works for the last row it exists in the table, I mean it works for the username that is placed on the last row in the table.

I'm certain I'm doing something wrong and I'm asking you what could be that wrong thig I'm doing ?

Comment: At least try to work around all those nested `if`'s.

Comment: What do you mean ? Remove the `if`'s and work like that ? That way I won't know where the problem is ...

Comment: a couple quick coding tips - your main if/elseif/else should be indented to the same level, they are not nested controls (except when you really are nesting them). Why duplicate $message['error'] to $error when you can just check !isset($message['error']). And you can remove your multiple return statements into just one return statement after the main if/elseif/else control block. You could also initialize $message['error'] = true; before the main if blocks, then only set it to false that one time it happens. This should make your code more concise/readable, etc.

Comment: And, for the record NEVER store any password in plain text. And your UPDATE may have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: OK. I'll try that, but this way is readable to me :) @Joe, I'm not storing the password as plain text, at least I think so, I'm making a hash of the pass with a random salt key and I'm storing the hash, and not the actual password. And you say I might have SQL injection vulnerability with the `UPDATE` , are you sure ? And if yes how can I prevent that ?

Comment: You are putting the username in as a variable substitution in the UPDATE, it should be a ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is hard to read, but one error I can see is where you select your user:

```
$sql = 'SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
                    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
                        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$cusrn,$newPass);
```

You are using the new password to select a user before you have changed it, so that will fail / you will not find a user.

By the way, if you want your admin to be able to change passwords of different users, you need to exclude the admin user from some of the password comparison functions.

For example (assuming you set your admin user in a session):

```
if(!(strcmp($oldPass,$passw) == false) || $_SESSION['admin_user']) {
```

Comment: I see, I tried without the `bind_param()` but I get the same result, I can change the password only to one user and not for all. So what should I do ?

Comment: @Roland You are doing your old password comparison later on so you should not use the password in the `WHERE` condition. Just get the user and his / her password and move on to the comparison.

Comment: Now it looks like this `$sql = 'SELECT username,password FROM user';
       if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($usrn,$passw);
        if($stmt->fetch()) {` but I get this `The current Username is incorrect` even though that username exists in the table. It only works for the first row now, the username placed on the first row in the table.

Comment: @Roland You do need your `WHERE` condition in the sql statement, but just with the username and not with the password.

Comment: Well, I would only like to change the pass for the admin, the user that is currently logged in ... not for all if possible, I will only implement that further in the development process ...

Comment: OK. Now it works. This is what I did : `$sql = 'SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE username = ?';
       if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$cusrn);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($usrn,$passw);
        if($stmt->fetch()) {` I followed your advice and removed password = ? and bind only one parameter, and it works fine :) Now I can change  password to any user. My question is, how would I do to be able to change the password only to the logged in user ?

Comment: @Roland I thought the admin should be able to change any password. Anyway, you can easily add another check to compare the logged in user to the sent in username.

Comment: Yes, but I also would like to have each user be able to change only their own password. For the moment, I, as an admin, can change any user password as long as I know the usernames, but I don't want the users to be able to do the same thing, only to their username they should be able to do that ...

Comment: @Roland That's what my edit allows, only people who have `$_SESSION['admin_user']` set to `true` can edit passwords regardless whether they know the old one.